# Getting the handle of a hidden form

Tags: c#, windows

I have a console application (`SRMan.exe`) which derives from `System.Windows.Forms.Form`. I could be able to hide the form while exe is running. code i used is here

```
    this.Opacity = 0;
    this.Size = new Size(0, 0);
    this.Location = new Point(-100, -100);
    this.Visible = false;
```

Aslo, configured the form properties `ShowIcon` and `ShowInTaskbar` to false.

but i could not able to get the Window handle of the of that running process.code i used is here

```
Process[] process1 = Process.GetProcessesByName("SRMan");
IntPtr pt = process1[0].MainWindowHandle;
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Karim.

Answer (score 2):

At what point are you calling:

```
Process[] process1 = Process.GetProcessesByName("SRMan");
IntPtr pt = process1[0].MainWindowHandle;
```

pt will be returned as zero or "MainWindowHandle" may throw an exception if the main window handle hasn't been created yet.

Try changing your code to:

```
Process[] process1 = Process.GetProcessesByName("SRMan");
process1[0].WaitForInputIdle();
IntPtr pt = process1[0].MainWindowHandle;
```

as this will force your code to wait until the process is fully loaded.
([MSDN article)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforinputidle.aspx)

As an example, the following code works fine for me:

```
 private Thread thd;

 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {            
     thd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GetHandle));
     thd.Start();
     this.Opacity = 0;
     this.Size = new Size(0, 0);
     this.Location = new Point(-100, -100);
     this.Visible = false;
 }

 private void GetHandle()
 {
     Process[] process1 = Process.GetProcessesByName("WindowsFormsApplication12.vshost");
     process1[0].WaitForInputIdle();
     IntPtr pt = process1[0].MainWindowHandle;
     MessageBox.Show(pt.ToString());
 }
```

Comment: Just read you're calling Process.GetProcessByName() from a seperate app.
I was getting the same issue as you until I added the WaitForInputIdle() method and it worked for me :)

Comment: +1. The `process1[0].WaitForInputIdle();` is the important part to remember.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you can't just grab the handle from the form's `Handle` property?
Anything that derives from the `Control` class, which Forms do, will have a `Handle` property.

Why are you resorting to grabbing it from the process?

Comment: I would be starting the process(SRMan.exe) from another process and I have to post the messages to that running process. So i need to use 
Process[] process1 = Process.GetProcessesByName("SRMan");
IntPtr pt = process1[0].MainWindowHandle;

Comment: as Sk93 points out, try using process1[0].WaitForInputIdle();  That has worked for me in the past as well.